# Using Boolean Logic to clean DF in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, series

df

```
shape   square
shape   circle
animal   NaN
NaN dog
NaN cat
NaN fish
color   red
color   blue
```

desired_df

```
shape   square
shape   circle
animal  dog
animal  cat
animal  fish
color   red
color   blue
```

I have a df contains information that needs to be normalized.

I have noticed a pattern that indicates how to join the columns and normalize the data.

If in Col1 != NaN and Col2 == NaN and directly in the following row Col1 == NaN and Col2 != NaN, then then values from Col1 and Col2 should be joined. This continues until arriving to a row that contains values Col1 != NaN and Col2 !=NaN
.

Is there a way to solve this in `pandas`?

The first step that I am thinking of is to create an additional column in order containing True/False values in order to determine what columns to join, however, once doing that, I am not sure how to assign the value in Col1 to all of the relevant values in Col2.

Any suggestions to arrive at desired result?

Comment: It is better if you provide a MCVE (copy-pastable data) instead of a print of the DataFrame

Comment: The question is not related to regex, hence I removed all the regex mentioning from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your identified pattern is a heuristic which, nevertheless, I struggle to follow, you can instead try [`pd.Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html) and [`pd.Series.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.bfill.html) to reach your desired result:

```
df[0] = df[0].ffill()
df[1] = df[1].bfill()
```

Then drop duplicates:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()

print(df)

        0       1
0   shape  square
1   shape  circle
2  animal     dog
4  animal     cat
5  animal    fish
6   color     red
7   color    blue
```

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate a bit more on what does `ffill()` and `bfill()` do?

Comment: @Fozoro, Sure they stand for "front fill" and "back fill", or "fill forwards" / "fill backwards". The methods fill null values (e.g. `NaN`) with non-`NaN` values either before or after.

Comment: @jpp Thank you very much